# Moving files lead to dependency issues

Tags: java, spring, maven

I moved some files into new packages so that things would make more sense, but this has resulted in my dependencies getting messed up.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
```

These lines give "cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'" with the advice of adding a maven dependency. If I do this nothing changes within the pom.xml file. Also the pom has errors with "spring-boot-starter-frontData-jpa" and "org.springframework.frontData" saying dependency not found.

Everything worked fine before but is messed up now. I've tried invalidate & restart which doesn't solve anything, undoing the changes also doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have an idea on this? The pom.xml file can be found below. Also might be important I'm working on intellij.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>be.uantwerpen.idlab.dust</groupId>
    <artifactId>initializr</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>dust-initializr</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-frontData-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.frontData</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-frontData-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ainslec</groupId>
            <artifactId>picocog</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>dust-initializr</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: what are those frontData dependency?

Comment: **I've tried invalidate & restart which doesn't solve anything** do you happen to use IntelliJ IDEA and recently updated to 2021.1 ?

Comment: @gtiwari333 not entirely sure, I got this project from another guy.

Comment: @IllyaKysil I'm working on intellij but I haven't updated recently.

Comment: I bet this one `<version>RELEASE</version>` is wrong!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by reverting changes through git.
Re-doing the moves didn't give the same error this time.

Not shure where this error came from and advice is welcome should it happen again.

Comment: What happened is that some find-and-replace was not as intelligent as it should have been. It looks like the string `boot` got changed to `frontData`.